# laravel 7 not required fields in forms

Tags: php, laravel

I created register form and post form.

register.blade.php

```
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h1 style="border-bottom: solid yellow;"><strong>Formulaire d'inscription</strong></h1>
                <p><small><strong>Ces données permettent à la société d'offir un service client optimal, notamment en
                            optimisant les résultats dans vos recherches.</strong></small></p>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        @csrf
                        <h3><strong>Vos identifiants</strong></h3>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Adresse mail</label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                                       name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                                <span>
                                    <img class="info_icon" src="{{asset('icons/info.png')}}"
                                         title="L’adresse mail permet de vous connecter au service.
L’adresse mail vous permet d’échanger avec les autres utilisateurs
L’adresse mail n’est pas visible des autres utilisateurs.">
                                </span>
                                @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Mot de passe</label>

                            <div class="col-md-8 show_hide_password">
                                <input id="password" type="password"
                                       class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password"
                                       required autocomplete="new-password">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="field_icon"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash "
                                                                                   aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                <span><img class="info_icon" src="{{asset('icons/info.png')}}" title="Mot de passe. Doit contenir au moins :
8 caractères minimum
25 caractères maximum
1 chiffre minimum
1 lettre majuscule minimum
1 caractère spécial minimum: &~#‘{}[]()-|`_\/^ @ = +$ % *?, .  ;:!"></span>

                                @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Confirmation mot
                                de passe</label>

                            <div class="col-md-8 show_hide_password">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control"
                                       name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="field_icon"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash "
                                                                                   aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h3><strong>Informations personnelles</strong></h3>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="sex" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Civilité</label>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexe" id="exampleRadios1"
                                           value="M" checked>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                        Male
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="sexe" id="exampleRadios2"
                                           value="F">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                                        Female
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Prénom</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror"
                                       name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
                                @error('name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="firstname" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Nom</label>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="firstname" type="text"
                                       class="form-control @error('firstname') is-invalid @enderror" name="firstname"
                                       value="{{ old('firstname') }}" required autocomplete="firstname" autofocus>
                                @error('firstname')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="address" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Adresse</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="address" type="text"
                                       class="form-control @error('address') is-invalid @enderror" name="address"
                                       value="{{ old('address') }}" autocomplete="address" autofocus>
                                <span><img class="info_icon" src="{{asset('icons/info.png')}}" title='L’adresse postale nous permet de :
￭ faire des statistiques et analyses marketing, afin de comprendre comment vous utilisez nos services.
￭ vous proposez du contenu personnalisé et améliorer votre expérience utilisateur
￭ vous envoyez des annonces parues sur notre site, près de chez vous  et susceptibles de vous intéresser.
Vos données sont modifiables, supprimables à tout moment depuis votre espace mon compte "mon profil"'></span>
                                @error('address')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="city" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Ville</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="city" type="text" class="form-control @error('city') is-invalid @enderror"
                                       name="city" value="{{ old('city') }}" autocomplete="city" autofocus>
                                @error('city')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="zipcode" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Code postale</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="zipcode" type="text"
                                       class="form-control @error('zipcode') is-invalid @enderror" name="zipcode"
                                       value="{{ old('zipcode') }}" autocomplete="zipcode" autofocus>
                                @error('zipcode')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Numéro de téléphone</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror"
                                       name="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" autocomplete="phone" autofocus>
                                <span>
                                    <img class="info_icon" src="{{asset('icons/info.png')}}"
                                           title='Si vous souhaitez être contacté par téléphone,
                                            sms par les autres utilisateurs du site qui répondernt à vos annonces.
                                            Vos données sont modifiables,
                                             supprimables  à tout moment depuis votre espace mon compte " mon profil" '>
                                </span>
                                @error('phone')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="birthday" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Date de
                                naissance</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="birthday" type="date"
                                       class="form-control @error('birthday') is-invalid @enderror" name="birthday"
                                       value="{{ old('birthday') }}" required autocomplete="birthday" autofocus>
                                <span><img class="info_icon" src="{{asset('icons/info.png')}}"
                                           title="Il faut avoir au minimum 18 ans pour s'inscrire"></span>
                                @error('birthday')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="pseudo" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right">Nom d'utilisateur
                                (pseudo)</label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="pseudo" type="text"
                                       class="form-control @error('pseudo') is-invalid @enderror" name="pseudo"
                                       value="{{ old('pseudo') }}" required autocomplete="pseudo" autofocus>
                                <span><img class="info_icon" src="{{asset('icons/info.png')}}"
                                           title="le pseudo s'affiche dans l'annonce. A défaut de pseudo, votre nom s'affiche."></span>
                                @error('pseudo')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="avatar" class="col-md-2 col-form-label text-md-right"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input id="avatar" type="file"
                                       class="form-control @error('avatar') is-invalid @enderror" name="avatar"
                                       autocomplete="avatar" accept="image/*">
                                @error('avatar')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                            <p style="padding-top: 7px;padding-left: 21px;">(facultatif)</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="g-recaptcha"
                                     data-sitekey="{{env('GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_KEY')}}">
                                </div>
                                <span role="alert" class="invalid-feedback d-block">
                                    @error('g-recaptcha-response')
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>
                                    @enderror
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="scales" name="scales" checked>
                            <label>Je souhaite recevoir des offres des partenaires du site susceptibles de
                                m'intéresser</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="scales" name="scales" checked required>
                            <label>Je déclare avoir lu <a href="#">les conditions générales de services</a> et <a
                                    href="#">les conditions d'utilisations</a></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="scales" name="scales" checked required>
                            <label>J'accepte les <a href="#">Conditions Générales de Vente</a> et les <a href="#">Conditions
                                    Générales d'Utilisations</a></label>

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8x` offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"
                                        style="background-color:gold; border-color:gold;">
                                    Crée mon compte
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".show_hide_password a").on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if ($(this).prev('input').attr("type") == "text") {
                    $(this).prev('input').attr('type', 'password');
                    $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-eye-slash");
                    $(this).find('i').removeClass("fa-eye");
                } else if ($(this).prev('input').attr("type") == "password") {
                    $(this).prev('input').attr('type', 'text');
                    $(this).find('i').removeClass("fa-eye-slash");
                    $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-eye");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
@endsection


@section('scripts')
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

@endsection
```

registercontroller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'firstname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'birthday' => ['required', 'date', 'before:-18 years'],
            'city' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string','unique:users'],
            'zipcode' => ['required', 'integer'],
            'pseudo' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'min:8',
                'max:25',
                'confirmed',
                'regex:/[a-z]/',      // must contain at least one lowercase letter
                'regex:/[A-Z]/',      // must contain at least one uppercase letter
                'regex:/[0-9]/',      // must contain at least one digit
                'regex:/[@$!%*#?&]/',
            ],
            'avatar' => ['image', 'mimes:jpg,jpeg,bmp,png,svg', 'max:3000'] ,
            'sexe' => ['required', Rule::in(['F','M'])],
            'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|recaptcha'
            ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if(request()->has('avatar')){
            $avataruploaded = request()->file('avatar');
            $avatarname = time() . '.' . $avataruploaded->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $avatarpath = public_path('/images/');
            $avataruploaded->move($avatarpath, $avatarname);
            return User::create([
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
                'address' => $data['address'],
                'city' => $data['city'],
                'phone' => $data['phone'],
                'zipcode' => $data['zipcode'],
                'pseudo' => $data['pseudo'],
                'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
                'avatar' => '/images/' . $avatarname,
                'sexe' => $data['sexe'],
            ]);
        }
        if($data['sexe'] == "M"){
            $avatar = "/images/avatar-male.jpg";
        }else{
            $avatar = "/images/Female-Avatar.jpg";
        }
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'city' => $data['city'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'zipcode' => $data['zipcode'],
            'pseudo' => $data['pseudo'],
            'birthday' => $data['birthday'],
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'sexe' => $data['sexe'],
            'avatar' => $avatar,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I want that in register form, address and number not to be required when registering. Can add if want but if don't want don't add. And in post form, I don't need date and time to be required. I try to delete required from the controller but it isn't working. Does someone have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Seems like, on your mysql this fields are required. Which error you get after delete `required`?

Comment: It's writing this : Le champ adresse doit être une chaîne de caractères. its error what i added when it's not adding.  But where i can lave for in mysql it's not required?

Comment: Change `'phone' => ['required', 'string','unique:users'],` to `'phone' => ['nullable', 'string','unique:users'],` and change `'address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],` to `'address' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255'],` then try to submit again, and give me feedback here

Comment: i have this error : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'address' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `firstname`, `address`, `city`, `phone`, `zipcode`, `pseudo`, `birthday`, `email`, `password`, `sexe`, `avatar`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (denis, denis, ?, ?, ?, ?, brazillll777, 2000-01-01, testeur66@gmail.com,

Comment: Do you have data on your database, if you delete everything and migrate the database again, then do you have problem to do that?

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'address' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `firstname`, `address`, `city`, `phone`, `zipcode`, `pseudo`, `birthday`, `email`, `password`, `sexe`, `avatar`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (denis, denis, ?, ?, ?, ?, denideni, 2000-02-20, testeur@gmail.com,

Comment: I answered your question, if you migrate again then it will work. But it will delete all of your database and create fresh one. So,  it you dont want to migrate, then you need to configure it from phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Change :

```
'phone' => ['required', 'string','unique:users'],
'address' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
```

to

```
'phone' => ['nullable', 'string','unique:users'],
'address' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:255'],
```

And your `2019_04_19_071925_create_users_table` migrations, add `nullable()`, as like :

```
$table->string("phone")->nullable();
$table->string("address")->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

need to add nullable in mysql and what asked in comment thanks for your help